# How to get OidcUser in spring-resource-server instead just Jwt in @AuthenticationPrincipal?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring-boot(2.5.0 version) application with org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server dependency and **application.properties**:
`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs`.
When I use @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation it injects *org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt*. Instead how to get *OidcUser*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your security configuration the `oauth2Login()` client is configured with an OIDC provider you can just inject it using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

```java
@GetMapping("/user")
public String userInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
    ...
}
```